# Getting write access to a directory path in flutter API 30 and above

Tags: android, flutter

I want to know how to get write access to a directory path in flutter on API 30 and above. Currently, I cannot find a working complete solution to it anywhere on the internet.

And it would be very grateful if anyone could answer this completely in a detailed way or provide a working sample project.

Comment: Its the same as in the earlier Android versions.

Comment: No, it's not previously on android I just have to add ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"``` but that doesn't work for API 30 and greater.

Comment: Indeed for Android 29 you had to add that. And indeed it only works for 29. But luckily you do not need it or anything else for 30+. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) when I try to write a file in android in any directory except app directory and downloads. I want to know how I can request access through the Storage Access Framework (SAF) so that I can write to any location with user permission. In the above question, I'm asking for a detailed solution for that in flutter as I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I also know I can get access with this permission ```android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``` but I can't use it. Google rejected my app and said that I can request access to the directory from users in safe ways without this permission.

Comment: Show the code where you try to create a file and then fails. Put all code in your post. Not in a comment. Make full path and filename clear to us

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I know this is not accurately an answer to my question that's why not marked as an answer but this could be useful for those who wanted the "write access" for saving a file in a user-defined location with the native save dialog.

1. Add [flutter_file_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_dialog) plugin in pubspec.yaml. (Version 2.3.0 used in this answer)
2. Create a function like this.

```
Future<String?> saveFileInUserDescribedLocation() async {

    //Create parameters for save file dialog
    //Saving a file through Uint8List data
    final params = SaveFileDialogParams(
        mimeTypesFilter: ["application/pdf"],
        data: Uint8List.fromList(bytes),
        fileName: 'Test.pdf');

    //You can also use a source file path to save a file through its path like this
    //final params = SaveFileDialogParams(
    //    sourceFilePath: tempPdfPath, mimeTypesFilter: ["application/pdf"]);


    //Now provide parameters and save the file.
    //It will return the file path chosen by the user to save the file after saving the file.
    final filePath = await FlutterFileDialog.saveFile(params: params);

    debugPrint("Save filePath: $filePath");
    return filePath;
}
```

2. Then execute the saveFileInUserDescribedLocation() function. It will provide a native dialog to the user asking the user to choose a location to save and then saves the file.

```
ElevatedButton( 
    onPressed: () { await saveFileInUserDescribedLocation(); },
    child: const Text("Save File")
)
```